# How to write elastic search query equivalent to normal query?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to form elastic search query for below query?

```
"or (test.period.fromDate >= :fromDate "
+ "and test.period.toDate < :toDate)"
```

I tried this, but throwing compile time error in must method.

> The method must(RangeFilterBuilder) is undefined for the type RangeFilterBuilder

```
.should(rangeFilter("test.period.fromDate").gte(sc.getFromDate())
.must(rangeFilter("test.period.toDate").lt(sc.getToDate())))
```

Comment: If you have a compilation problem, please provide your compilation error so we can exactly know what is not working.

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you forgot a parenthesis. This should be :

```
.should(
  rangeFilter("test.period.fromDate").gte(sc.getFromDate())
)
.must(
  rangeFilter("test.period.toDate").lt(sc.getToDate())
)
```

The `must` part shoud apply after the `should` part and not on the `rangeFilter` part.

Also I think you might have another problem based on the SQL-like query you provided. I think the query should be :

```
.should(
  boolQuery().must(
    rangeFilter("test.period.fromDate").gte(sc.getFromDate())
  )
  .must(
    rangeFilter("test.period.toDate").lt(sc.getToDate())
  )
)
```